# JSONLoader and textures R61

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently updated to version r61 from r58 and have found that with JSONLoader even if i only want to return geometry I am still getting a 404 on a texture call from a shader in my model.js file.

```
loadModel: function( label, domobject, callback ) {
        var model_path   = '/models/js/' + label + '.js';
        var texture_place = '/textures/' + label + '.jpg';
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader()


        function onLoad(event) {
            domobject.append( Set.renderer.domElement );
        }

        var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( texture_place, null, onLoad );
        loader.load( model_path, function ( geometry ) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture}); 
            Set.asset = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            Set.asset.position.x = Set.asset.position.y = Set.asset.position.z = 0;
            Set.asset.scale.x = Set.asset.scale.y = Set.asset.scale.z = 1;
            if ( callback ) callback(); 
        });         
    },
```

I am setup this way as to prevent models from loading up black and then having the texture pop on, which is working great. The behavior I expected with JSONLoader was that

loader.load(model_path, function (geometry, materials) would dig into the model file and look for materials and textures and that just specifying 'geometry' would ignore shader / texture.

Furthermore,

Is there a more simple way to use JSONLoader it's texturePath argument and an onLoad function to ensure that my geo doesn't get rendered before a texture is finished loading ?

Thanks!